# find out rotation using phase correlation in matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, rotation, fft

I just want to find out the rotation angle between two images (same images but only different thing is rotation) but I'm stuck in this problem for almost 3 weeks. The algorithm given at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_correlation is only using the radon transform and phase correlation method but it doesn't work. Anyone can help me?

Comment: _In image processing, phase correlation is a method of image registration, and uses a fast frequency-domain approach to estimate the relative **translative** offset between two similar images._ Try to apply rotation and then compute a bin to bin distance between the images. if there is no noise and the images are the same the euclidean distance should be fine

Comment: You'd improve your chances or getting useful help if you'd show the code you have so far, and explained why it's not satisfactory to you in its current form.

Comment: @CapeCode Code I should, thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, this kind of problem is solved with a Fourier-Mellin algorithm, Matlab implementation [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/3000-fourier-mellin-based-image-registration--with-gui-).

A potential approach is the use of a log-polar transform prior to phase correlation. The log-polar sampling maps changes in uniform scaling and rotation into translations along the radial and circumferential axes. See the complete description of the algorithm in this paper:

> Reddy, B. S. and Chatterji, B. N., An FFT-Based Technique for
>   Translation, Rotation, and Scale-Invariant Image Registration, IEEE
>   Transactions on Image Processing, Vol. 5, No. 8, August 1996

If you have the image processing toolbox r2014a or later, there is a built-in function that does exactly that, it's called [`imregcorr`](http://mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imregcorr.html)

If you don't have the toolbox, you can [download the function to map an image in polar coordinates](http://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/47238-impolar-m) (for pure rotations). For scale and rotation, [here](http://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27023-log-polar-image-sampling) is an implementation of the log-polar transform.