# How to find that how much is the image shifted from the original one in MATLAB?

Tags: image, matlab

I have two images (Im1 and Im2) which are shifted and/or rotated from each other with some pixel.

Is there a way to find out the value of how much the image is rotated/shifted ? 
I used the following command but it just show me the visualization.

```
imshowpair(AA,BB,'falsecolor');
```

[AA and BB Files are here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/nkpqg1wzaeb1npz/AAAA3lklfQVHRLbPj2FlzzXJa?dl=0)

But I am interested only in there shifted/rotated value.

Comment: There is no easy way to calculate this -- you will have to come up with an algorithm or find a journal article with a good method. The naïve implementation would perform a 2D cross correlation of AA and BB, but at a variety of rotations. But that is a search in three variables (x, y, and theta) and might be too slow.

Comment: You might want to look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27030889/find-out-rotation-using-phase-correlation-in-matlab) question and answer for a couple hints on how to do that